# Python - Select tuple from a list contains string of another list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

Newbie here,

I have a list :

```
a = ['a', 'b']

b = [ ('a','b','c'), ('a','c', 'd'), ('b','c','z'), ('d','c','j')]
```

I want to create a new list from b that contains item of a

I want to have new list contains `[('a','b','c'), ('a','c', 'd'), ('b','c','z')]`

I make this code :

```
result = [i for i in b if item for item in a in b]
```

and i got error :

*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment*

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

Code:

```
a = ['a', 'b']
result =[]
b = [ ('a','b','c'), ('a','c', 'd'), ('b','c','z'), ('d','c','j')]

for i in b:
  for j in a:
    if j in i:
      result.append(i)
      break
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'z')]
```